# Validate T-SQL programmability objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

Is there a way to validate programmability objects in SQL Server 2008?

I have a database with ~500 programmability objects which depend on other programmability objects (not only tables).

If I do some refactoring, it is very hard find other objects which are broken by the changes. For example if I change the parameter count...

Original state of database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSomeText]() RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS BEGIN RETURN 'asdf' END

/* uses "GetSomeText()" function */
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOtherText]() RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS BEGIN RETURN [dbo].[GetSomeText]() + '-qwer' END
```

Now I do some refactoring (add parameter `@Num` to `GetSomeText()` function):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSomeText](@Num int) RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS BEGIN RETURN 'asdf' + CAST(@Num as nvarchar(max)) END
```

Now the function `GetOtherText()` is broken, because it is calling `GetSomeText()` function without a required parameter.

Is there a way to get information about this error?

Currently I script every programmability object as `ALTER`, run the alter script, and check for errors. This way looks to be too complex (and is hard to use in T-SQL only enviroment).

**EDIT:**

Thanks for answers! I know how to get dependenices or list of all objects.
The problem is in checking the body of object. If I get the dependency, is there other way to check validity than run `ALTER` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try introducing some automated database developer/unit testing.

With 500 SQL objects it would be onerous to go back and 'retro fit' for them all. Best approach might be to incrementally create these tests as the need to refactor/change existing APIs/create new SQL objects arises

These automated tests could then be included as part of your overall continous integration approach. Note for the example given you would still have the issue of finding existing dependencies. But once there was sufficient test coverage the tests should highlight any breaking changes introduced.

I have created a test tool that might be of use - but there are a number of others out there:

http://dbtestunit.wordpress.com/

Comment: I'll take way with automaticaly generated tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to find the dependency.  You can, however, find everything that references the name of the object you're changing like this:

```
 select OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) as objectDefinition, *
   from sys.objects o
  where o.type in ('P', 'FN')
    and OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) like '%GetSomeText%'
```

`o.type in ('P', 'FN')` limits the search to P - Procedures and FN - Scalar Functions.  Check out more info about OBJECT_DEFINITION: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to get dependency is to use `sp_depends`.  This **does** work with functions, but you need to be sure you are in the right DB context:

```
USE MyDatabase
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'dbo.FunctionName'
```

This will show you any object whether it be a function, stored proc, table, or view that has a dependency for the listed object.

This is not always accurate with cross-database dependencies, though, so be aware.

Comment: actually, sp_depends will only return tables that are used in the function/stored proc that you pass in.  Check out the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx

Comment: @milimetric - have you tried running it?  I tested on a function in my 2008 r2 database and it returned a function calling that function.

Comment: yes, I tried it on 2008 r2 for a stored proc.  It doesn't return the stored proc that references it.  Hm...

Comment: ok, just ran it on a function and it DOES give you dependencies for that.  But not stored procedures.  Very bizarre as the documentation doesn't mention this.